# How to test old rails2 application in rails3 environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-2

I am learning how to build rails application. And I found a very helpful blog  github,
      https://github.com/balgarath/video-app

But this project is done 4 years ago.

I trying to follow the instructions to compile it. But I cant run it without the gemfile...

```
user@user:~/test2/video-app$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
Could not locate Gemfile

user@user:~/test2/video-app$ rake db:create
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in        
RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- scrubyt

saasbook@saasbook:~/test2/video-app$ rake gems:install
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in         RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb
```

rake aborted!
no such file to load -- scrubyt
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Does anyone know how to run these old applications in my localhost?

I just try to run it and learn from the codes...

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably much easier to understand the functionality and adopt it into a new Rails application instead of trying to get it running. You will run into multiple issues like outdated gems, changed APIs and so on.

Good luck.

Btw. you are not *compiling* any code. Ruby is an interpreted language.